# VMWare VSphere on Ubuntu

Tags: vmware

I've downloaded and installed VSphere CLI 5.1.0, but I can't open it.

I've installed the dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml-libxml-perl libclass-methodmaker-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl perl-doc libarchive-zip-perl libsoap-lite-perl libdata-dump-perl
```

And then extract and execute the `vmware-install.pl` with the default options.

At the end of the installation, I got:

This installer has successfully installed both vSphere CLI and the vSphere SDK 
for Perl.

The following Perl modules were found on the system but may be too old to work 
with vSphere CLI:

```
Compress::Zlib 2.037 or newer 
Compress::Raw::Zlib 2.037 or newer 
IO::Compress::Base 2.037 or newer 
IO::Compress::Zlib::Constants 2.037 or newer 
UUID 0.03 or newer
```

I don't know how to update them.

Anyway, if I try to execute `vmwarectrl`:

```
sudo vmwarectrl 
Xlib:  extension "VMWARE_CTRL" missing on display ":0".
VMWARE_CTRL Extension not found.
```

If I run it with `gksu`, the display issue doesn't happen... just the "Extension not found"...

How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

---

### EDIT

I also ask it on [VMWare Communities forum](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2221210).

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the package from here http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libio-compress-perl

So I guess using a command like: `apt-get install libio-compress-perl*`

Comment: thanks! I do all this, and now I still getting: "VMWARE_CTRL Extension not found." I removed vmware and installed again, but it doens't work..

Comment: sorry :( after google around i am drawing blank. from what i can see the `vmwarectrl` is either not enabled in this build or it can not find it. you can try to see if your problem is related to this http://communities.vmware.com/thread/326868

Comment: well, didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Install `uuid-dev`:

```
apt-get install uuid-dev
```